# nginx reverse proxy to apache mod_wsgi django app

Tags: django, apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, mod-wsgi

Been trying to do this for a while and haven't found something that works.

I have a Django app deployed via Apache & mod_wsgi.  Apache listens on port 8080 and everything works fine when I access

`example.com:8080`

I have Nginx listening on port 80 serving a static site at `/`.

I'm trying to configure Nginx reverse proxy to Apache (Django) such that when I access `example.com/app` it should take me to the Django app.  This is my configuration so far:

```
location /app/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                }
```

I have tried using/not_using the trail slash both after `app` and the `proxy_pass` address.

However, I am always getting a 404 Not Found error.

Can someone please help me to correctly set the reverse proxy in Nginx?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sanity check: who is giving the 404 error?  Nginx or apache (if you look in apache's logs, do you see a 404 error).  First guess is that nginx isn't stripping off the /app when it proxies the request, but I always have to double check configs (and in general find reverse proxies are much happier if you proxy /app to backend/app vs just backend because of assumptions on /)

Comment: Hi @Foon thanks for your reply.  There is no 404 error in apache's logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME='/app/'
```

Add this at settings.py and restart Django.  The value should match locations entry in nginx to work it correctly.

Comment: Hi @Bimal thanks for your reply.  This didn't work, and if I make this change then the app does not work well in `example.com:8080` (e.g. login won't work)

Comment: After making this change app is expected to work ONLY via apache under /app/ location. Both way it wont work.